# Upgrading my VM instance

Tags: virtual-machine

My VM instance recommended I increase my current CPU and memory from "1 CPU and 3.5GB memory to 1 CPU and 4.0GB".

I did exactly what it asked me to do; then I get this message:

> Starting VM instance "razedembersonlineinstance1" failed. Error: The zone 'projects/razedembersvps/zones/europe-west3-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

My last VM instance was in exactly the same place, but I had 2 CPU and 6.5GB memory.

So how does that work?

Comment: Are you using x86 OS or hardware? The 3.5GB number sounds suspiciously like the 32-bit limitations on RAM. If so, you'll need to upgrade to a 64-bit system.

Comment: What is the host and guest OS? What software are you using to run the VM?

Comment: No guys, my dumb *** mistake. When choosing the VM i did not look at the area listing believing that Zone europe-west3-b was located in LONDON! DOH, sorry guys, i realised when i did a check through everything i had done to create the instance. Then cross referenced with the Zone locations and boom, i chose Frankfurt/Germany instead. Sorry for not getting in contact sooner, i couldnt log in and with holidays. My mistake. And i truely thank you for your suggestions Disco1969